# How do I model / diagram turn-based combat?

Tags: game-design, turn-based, combat

I'm developing a turn-based combat system for an RPG, and I'd like to know if there is any kind of best practice around diagrammatically modelling something like this.

The ideal modelling paradigm would capture quite a few things, including:

- entities (and their stats/status)
- entity actions / interactions
- positioning
- terrain effects
- temporal effects

Do I use something from UML? BPMN? A combination? Do I home-bake something?

To clarify: I'm not looking for any advice on designing the system. I'm already quite far along with that. I'm looking for a good way to diagram the model.

Comment: Hi Fenja. Unfortunately this question sounds like asking for advice for a complete game, which is too broad to be answered by a single answer here. In general, there are no best practises for most game-related techniques. If you are unsure, start working on one idea and see if it works. If you get stuck on a specific step, that would make a better question to be answered here.

Comment: Hi @TomTsagk. You misunderstand. I'm not asking for advice on developing the system; I'm asking if there is a specific diagrammatic technique that would be well-suited to representing a sophisticated turn-based combat model.

Comment: I would suggest editing your answer to focus on the information you are looking for. Also I'd advice against using names like "UML" or "BPMN", because some people (including me) might be unfamiliar with what they mean. It's better to use full names.

Comment: @TomTsagk Okay, I have clarified my question. With regards terms such as "UML" and "BPMN", I'm confident that anybody capable of answering my question will be amply familiar with them. Thanks for your suggestions :)

Comment: I know of relatively few standardized diagramming techniques for game design. Machinations could cover this, but I think the result would be less clear than using your own custom diagramming style.

Comment: I'm only trying to help you make your question more approachable to more people. I've created turn-based games in the past, both similar to pokemon style, and something influenced by Final Fantasy tactics, yet I'm unfamiliar with the terms you mentioned, so I don't understand what you are looking for. I'm sure there are more people like that here. If you are happy to not want to give them a chance to help you, that is your call.

Comment: @DMGregory Machinations looks very interesting. Thank you for the suggestion!

Comment: I'm not working in the industry, just as a disclaimer. I personally only create UML class diagrams and mostly on paper. Most UML tools are kinda restrictice with the benefit of supporting code generation. I use paper because it tends to be faster for me personally. Other than that it's good to be aware of common gamedev related programming patterns when modeling. Good luck!

Comment: @FenjaLouwrens It doesnt seem like you need a programming diagram. It seems more like you need some sort of Overview what effect does what (like attacking an enemy in cover gives him more defense, hitting from above deals more damage etc.) i would consider this part of the game concept less suitable for some sort of diagram.

Comment: @Bartimaeus Thank you, this is good advice.

Comment: @PSquall Oh, hmm. That's not a bad point. I will give it some thought!

Comment: @FenjaLouwrens In that case maybe take a look at some rulebooks for Tabletop systems, Those basicly do the same as you want to to - group model types, actions, terrains and status effects. There are some free out there. E.g.: Warmachine / Hordes

Comment: Use whatever you (and your team) are familiar and confortable with.

Of course, it also depends on the reason why you are doing this, if it's for programmers UML might be the best option, as the chances for them to know it is higher than BPMN (wild guess) which has a more high-level description due to be linked to the business, in this case, game mechanics(?).

I've already used a combination of UML and text description in the same situation you are, and I liked the results.

Comment: @PSquall That's a fabulous idea, thank you!

Comment: @MVCDS I suspect I'll end up doing something similar. I'll post the results in an answer when I'm done :)

Comment: You're approaching the subject from the wrong direction. What problem are you trying to solve by "diagrammatically modelling"? Why do you need to model it? What's wrong with simple "textual modelling" i.e. writing out paragraphs? What happens if you don't model it? The answers to these questions will eventually lead you onto the correct answer, as for now your request is too broad.

Answer (score -1):

I would use OOP and detailed UML diagrams. Obviously a class diagram will help you a lot, but the more you use, the more you will have an accurate idea of what you will have to do and how it works. I would also recommend a Use-Case and State diagram too, if you are willing to spend a little bit of time concepting the thing.

You will never find one perfect diagram to visualise everything; you'll probably have to do a bit of everyting, because each diagram has its particular meaning and usefulness.

If you are not familiar with these concepts and want to have a quick look,  [here](https://tallyfy.com/uml-diagram/) is a quick sum of the more used diagrams and why you should work on them.

> A UML diagram is a diagram based on the UML (Unified Modeling Language) with the purpose of visually representing a system along with its main actors, roles, actions, artifacts or classes, in order to better understand, alter, maintain, or document information about the system

Comment: This answer would be better if it included some details about what makes this particular diagramming approach suitable for this purpose specifically, or superior to the alternatives. An example of how such a diagram could he applied to this case would also be valuable.

Comment: Welcome to GDSE & thanks for participating. I agree with you that UML would likely address OP's needs, but as written, this answer doesn't address the specific interaction called out in the question. UML is a very broad subject with over a dozen different diagrams. Calling out a couple of the more useful diagrams is a good first step. This answer would be further improved if it followed up on that by directing readers in how those diagrams might specifically be applied to the question at hand.

Comment: A UML activity diagram might cover most of the functional process steps in a turn based design, since it the design is really an iteration of a turn across the entities in the system.  However, I think a game system can suddenly take on non-standard processes and events. (I am thinking of my own forays into designing board games) As @Pikalek stated, UML has several diagrams that might be coaxed into working, specifically in the Sequence type diagrams.

Comment: The author knows what the UML diagram is, he is looking for examples, and I am also looking for examples